# Jinja2 Zebra Striping (Alternating Rows)

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I'm creating a CSS striped effect using Jinja2 similar to:

```
table tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #0D1424;
}
```

(**NOTE:** this is not an option for my HTML templates, the CSS gets removed from the email.)

I'm attempting to use Jinja's [Tips and Tricks - Alternating Rows](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/tricks/#alternating-rows) to set up the CSS styles for each row of a table. However, even after reading the documentation for the helper function [`loop.cycle`](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/c6334b6cec6faf9075f785007130293ddae8c52a/src/jinja2/runtime.py#L579), I do not understand how it's supposed to be implemented.

**HTML:**

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr class="{{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}">
        <td>{{ item['column1'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item['column2'] }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

After much research, I stumbled across [Quick Zebra Striping in Rails](http://blog.flvorful.com/2007/08/12/quick-zebra-striping-in-rails), a Rails blog post with a similar `cycle` method:

CSS:

```
.odd {
   background: #0D1424;
}
```